# How to update all the items in ArrayList due to shift in drag and drop of recyclerview

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop, android-recyclerview, itemtouchhelper

I have a `RecyclerView` whose layout is a `GridLayout` of 3 columns. I am using ItemTouchHelper to drag and drop in the `GridLayout` of the `RecyclerView`. In my Adapter there is a method `onItemMove()` which notify me the items which i have moved. It only swaps those items in the `ArrayList` which I have dragged and dropped. But due to the drag and drop there is a shift in other elements as well. I want to update their positions as well in the `ArrayList`.

Here is the Adapter of my Recyclerview:

```
public class GridAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GridAdapter.MyViewHolder> implements com.sagar.quizdemo.helper.ItemTouchHelperAdapter {
    String[] str = {"Level 1", "Level 2", "Level 3", "Level 4", "Level 5", "Level 6", "Level 7", "Level 8", "Level 9"};
    List<String> itemList, actualList;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;
    private final OnStartDragListener mDragStartListener;

    public GridAdapter(Context context, OnStartDragListener dragStartListener) {
        this.context = context;
        mDragStartListener = dragStartListener;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        itemList = new ArrayList<>();
        actualList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(str));
    }

    public void getItemList(List<String> nameList) {
        int currentSize = itemList.size();
        itemList.clear();
        itemList.addAll(nameList);
        notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, currentSize);
        notifyItemRangeInserted(0, nameList.size());
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_level_row, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.textView.setText(itemList.get(position));
        // Start a drag whenever the handle view it touched
        holder.cardView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event) == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    mDragStartListener.onStartDrag(holder);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        Collections.swap(itemList, fromPosition, toPosition);
        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
        notifyItemChanged(fromPosition);
        notifyItemChanged(toPosition);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemDismiss(int position) {
        itemList.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements ItemTouchHelperViewHolder {

        CardView cardView;
        TextView textView;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.gameCard);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.gameText);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected() {
            itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClear() {
            itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
    }
}
```

if initially the list is :

```
{"Level 1", "Level 2", "Level 3", "Level 4", "Level 5", "Level 6", "Level 7", "Level 8", "Level 9"}
```

After I swap 2nd and 4th positioned elements in the RecyclerView. The updated list should look like this (**which I want**):

```
{"Level 1", "Level 5", "Level 2", "Level 3", "Level 4", "Level 6", "Level 7", "Level 8", "Level 9"}
```

But I am getting this updated list:

```
{"Level 1", "Level 5", "Level 3", "Level 4", "Level 2", "Level 6", "Level 7", "Level 8", "Level 9"}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that your problem is that you use `Collections.swap(itemList, fromPosition, toPosition);`, which swaps objects on the specified positions. So the output is correct. What you need, though:

```
String item = itemList.remove(fromPostion);
itemList.insert(item, toPosition);
```

Comment: I want to check the updated list. where can i check the updated list in the adapter after drag and drop? I cant check the list inside `onItemMove()`. I wanna compare the updated list with another list.

Comment: @Hiren, do you want to check if the final combination is right? Well, I would suggest to do so when all `RecyclerView`'s animations have finished. I think it can be done by using custom `ItemAnimator` suggested in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33710605/detect-animation-finish-in-androids-recyclerview

Answer (score 2):

Code [here](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf) working for me.

```
 @Override
public boolean onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
    if (fromPosition < toPosition) {
        for (int i = fromPosition; i < toPosition; i++) {
            Collections.swap(listData, i, i + 1);
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = fromPosition; i > toPosition; i--) {
            Collections.swap(listData, i, i - 1);
        }
    }
    notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This code working for me Thank you.....

Answer (score 1):

Try calling notifyDataSetChanged() in onItemMove menthod.

```
@Override
    public boolean onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
        notifyItemChanged(fromPosition);
        notifyItemChanged(toPosition);
        notifyDataSetChanged();    
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: But that is creating problem in drag and drop. The moment I am dragging an item. Its dropping immediately to the neighbour item.

Comment: dont use swap, when u swap it changes the position of your selected item with the position at where you drag the item

Comment: I am making a puzzle game where user can change position of the items by drag and drop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead. In your case, you will first have to find the index of the item to be replaced (fromPosition) and then add toPosition to that index.
[How to move specific item in array list to the first item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186681/how-to-move-specific-item-in-array-list-to-the-first-item)

Comment: I am making a puzzle game where user can change position of the items by drag and drop.