# How to animate recyclerView on notifyDataSetChanged?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation

I have a recyclerview which is a list of folders.
When I click on an item, the folders/files inside that folder is the new list.
I want to play animation of sliding out the old list and sliding in the new list.
It should look like entering or leaving a directory.

I have implemented it like this:

```kotlin
// rv : RecyclerView

rv.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_out_to_left))
adapter.list = list
rv.notifyDataSetChanged()
rv.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_in_from_right))
```

But only the later animation is showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is that notifyDataSetChanged() is quite destructive, it is probably getting called before your animation can get started.

My advice is to delay

```
adapter.list = list
rv.notifyDataSetChanged()
rv.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_in_from_right))
```

until

```
rv.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.slide_out_to_left))
```

has sufficient time to run.
Here is a link to a previous answer that shows how to setup a onAnimationFinished listener, which should listen for the first animation to finish.
[Detect animation finish in Android's RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33710605/detect-animation-finish-in-androids-recyclerview)

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),R.anim.slide_out_to_left);
        animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
              adapter.list = list;
              adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
              rv.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_in_from_right));
            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
        });
rv.startAnimation(animation));
```

Comment: but in that way, won't the old list that will be sliding out be replaced by new list?

Comment: Isn't that what you want, for the new list to replace the old list once the animation ends?

Comment: yes, but doesn't your code replace the list before the animation starts?